# pandas pct_change show unsupported operand type str and str

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
print type (analysis['SMA_22'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>


analysis['SMA_22'].fillna('0').pct_change()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

analysis.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 619 entries, 2012-12-03 00:00:00 to 2015-04-16 00:00:00
Data columns (total 3 columns):
SMA_22    598 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
```

anyone have idea why?

Edit1: showing .info() as requested

Comment: What is the dtype of 'SMA_22'? can you show the output put from `analysis.info()`

Comment: analysis.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 619 entries, 2012-12-03 00:00:00 to 2015-04-16 00:00:00
Data columns (total 3 columns):
SMA_22    598 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)

Comment: Please edit additional info into your question, thanks

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, it thinks the dtype of that column is string, could you try converting it to float and then try again : `analysis[SMA_22'] = analysis[SMA_22'].astype(np.float64)`

Comment: SMA_22    598 non-null float64, analysis['SMA_22'].fillna('0').pct_change() still failed with same error.

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem:

```
analysis['SMA_22'].fillna('0').pct_change()
```

This replaces `NaN` with the character value `'0'` I think you want this:

```
analysis['SMA_22'].fillna(0).pct_change()
```

Which replaces `NaN` with the integer/float value `0`

Comment: analysis['SMA_22'].fillna(0).pct_change(): InvalidOperation: comparison involving NaN

Comment: You'll have to post the full raw data then as there is something wrong happening as I've just tried with 0 and NaN values being filled and it works for me

Comment: Also what is your python, numpy and pandas version? I'm running python 3.4 64-bit, numpy 1.9.1 and pandas 0.16.0

Comment: for raw data, should I use analysis.values() to show data? is this what you want?

Comment: No, I want the original csv, txt file and the code you used to load the data

Comment: I don't have ta-lib installed, can you post the output from `analysis['SMA_22'].values`

Comment: OK, I managed to install TA_Lib and your code snippet works fine for me, can you please tell me what version numpy and pandas you are using and if possible upgrade and retry

Comment: pandas (0.13.1), numpy (1.8.2)

Comment: That is quite an old version of pandas, if possible please upgrade both pandas and numpy and see if this is resolved

Comment: I just upgraded both version to latest, analysis['SMA_22'].fillna(0).pct_change(): InvalidOperation: comparison involving NaN

Comment: Are you able to try using python 3?